# Perform unwind-segue with custom-class

Tags: ios, storyboard, segue, unwind-segue

I do not want to use a NavigationController for this.

I have a Segue(Show(Push) with a custom class UIStoryboardSegue) between two ViewControllers. Now i want to "pop" the current ViewController, after some reading i think this is called "unwind segue".

1. I have a UIButton that is added with code during runtime. How to i add the unwind segue to this button?
2. How do i use my custom class for the unwind segue animation? :

   ```
   override func perform()
   {
      let src = self.sourceViewController
       let dst = self.destinationViewController

       src.view.superview?.insertSubview(dst.view, belowSubview: src.view)
       dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0)

       UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25,
           delay: 0.0,
           options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut,
           animations: {
               src.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(src.view.frame.size.width * -1, 0)
           },
           completion: { finished in
               src.presentViewController(dst, animated: false, completion: nil)
       }
   )
   }
   ```